# Is there a more ideal way to send draw commands?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, synchronization

I'm still working on moving my android app over to OpenGL and i'm once again having an issue.

I have gotten to the point where everything FUNCTIONS, the only problem is that the animation seems a little juddery.

I'm monitoring the frame rates and seeing that the drawing thread isn't slowing down, but every once in a while, the main loop slows a bit and I suspect I'm having a problem I was worried about.

The way the app works is that as new objects (say for instance, enemies) are created, 2 objects are actually created. The first one is created and mapped in the main thread, and then in it's constructor, it creates a mesh object which is then added to a group to be drawn continuously by the renderer.

Every time an attribute for the object is changed, (such as its coordinates) The object relays the necessary command to its mesh counterpart (in this example to translate the mesh.)

It was suggested that this was thread safe communication, but i'm having my doubts. I also notice a greater amount of frame skip when new objects are created, I can fix this somewhat by reusing the same mesh object for identical Game objects, but I don't believe this will fix everything by itself.

Can you think of a way to make this more efficient and thread-safe?

Another possible solution: The game logic does not HAVE to go at full speed (realtime) I have it actually set up so that no updates are made untill 33 millis pass. So obviously, I should have plenty of time between frames to draw, can I set it up so that draw is only called on command in the thread (after the game logic has been updated)?

Comment: What method are you using to `relay` the state change of the mesh? I get the impression that is where you feel the slow-down occurs.

Comment: Also, if you are observing more frame-skip when new players are being created, what mechanism are you using to create them? Are they new threads? Are you using an `Executor`?

Comment: I don't currently implement any sort of relay such as wait() or Notify(). Also, the way I create new objects is by implementing a hash map of objects and assigning a unique key to each new object using .put. No they are not new threads and they are very simple objects. The enemy objects really only contain a few attributes and the methods needed to update them, and the mesh objects that they create are all squares which can be textured through a texture manager class which I implement. This may not be ideal but it lets me simply switch out the texture used for each frame.

Comment: While we are on the thread subject, I noticed that the common practice is to use sleep() method to stop a thread. I only really need my app to run at ~30 fps. so in the game loop I have some code that uses a for loop to control the thread until the time since the beginning of the last loop cycle is 33ms. I did this quite a long time ago but i'm starting to suspect that this could be causing some efficiency issues. Even if it's doing nothing in the loop, the loop is still running as fast as it can, as many times as it can, eating resources right?

Comment: It is certainly not a good design to hog the cpu unnecessarily. I am not yet clear how your code fits together but the tidiest way to implement something like this would be to take just long enough to calculate what the picture should be in the next frame and then sleep until that frame has been displayed. Sadly, this often involves a complete redesign.

Comment: OK basically, I need to make it so that the drawing thread only begins after the logic thread has ended. And then the logic thread only begins after the drawing thread has ended? This should be easy as far as i'm seeing from examples with the wait() and Notify() commands, but is this the best way to do it? It seems that it somewhat defeats the purpose of using more than one thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need something like a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

With one of these you could put your renderer on a schedule so it executes at 30fps leaving your main/control thread to do whatever it needs to do to the object map between frames.

I don't think you need any `wait/notify` interlocking as all you really need is to block access to the `map` while the renderer is walking it. To do this you just need to make the map `synchronized`. As this will only happen once every 1/30th of a second you are certainly not introducing a significant overhead.

Your main aim should be to put as little unnecessary load on the CPU as possible, this is the key to smooth multithread work. Try to spend as much time as possible either sleeping or blocked.

**Added**

> I subtract the time it took to loop from 33ms, and use the result to specify the length of sleep().

I wonder if that may be part of your issue. On a Windows machine you often get a 15ms resolution on the `currentTimeMillis` so your sleeps may end up hardly sleeping at all. It may be worth experimenting with a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` just to see if it improves your timing. ... oops ... this is Android isn't it. Still ... it may be worth a try.

Comment: I kinda used this idea but came up with something slightly different. Since in my case, I'm using RenderWhenDirty, the framework already exists to control the Rendering thread's execution. So I simply call wait() on the main thread immediately after calling request render. and then notify is called once the frame is finished drawing. I also came up with a more elegant solution than I was using to throttle the fps. I subtract the time it took to loop from 33ms, and use the result to specify the length of sleep(). So far that seems to work.

Comment: In that case I suggest you drill further in to find out where the choppiness is coming from. Threading issues may be the cause but it is more likely you are not blocking/sleeping in the right places.

Comment: I meant I JUST used this idea and it did help.The one other place i'm a little concerned is that it appears that occasionally, the Renderer draws the frame even without a request, I've read a bit about spurious wake ups and i'm wondering if thats happening to me?

Comment: Good to know we're getting somewhere. A `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` should avoid any spurious wakeup issues.